# confused: Why which Version Node.JS

Tags: node.js, gulp, installation, nvm

I have been trying to get Gulp.js to work for 3 days and have failed so far. I have now resorted to reinstalling Linux Mint 17.3 from scratch... I want to install Node.JS on my machine and then run Gulp.

On nodejs.org https://nodejs.org/en/download/package-manager/it says: 
two versions:

```
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -
curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_6.x | sudo -E bash -
and then
sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
```

How can I know which version to install? For running Gulp cli which is the best way forward?

On many sites I read **"do not use apt-get to install Node.JS"** They never mention a reason. Apparently, it is better to use NVM (??)

So, can anyone explain it to me? Which version do I install? setup_4? setup_6? Which way to install Node.JS is the best way? apt-get or NVM? and especially WHY?

Thanx,

Thom

Comment: Node.js v4 is LTS( Long Term Support) and will be until April of 2017 then v6 will be LTS. Using NVM you can install any version you want. Using `curl -sL https://deb.nodesource.com/setup_4.x | sudo -E bash -` you get only the latest(currently v4.4.4). I don't know why some people don't recomend it tho. I used apt-get and had no problems with it at all and i'm still using v4 but there wasn't v6 when i installed it. I would go for v6 now.

Comment: Thanx for the feedback Molda.

Answer (score 1):

> do not use apt-get to install Node.JS

In the past the distro packaging was ~~not so good~~ really bad and created problems. Also it was notoriously late in regards of the latest node version available. I m not sure today about apt, but on my fedora 23 i m still getting provided node@0.10. So for me it s a no go.

> Apparently, it is better to use NVM

Node Version Manager helps to get setup and running quickly. It also helps you to switch between old/new versions very very quickly. awesome tool for developers.

> V4? V6?

Depends of your task and its goal.

For example, you are creating a build chain for front end development, you may go for v6 because only the developers will be impacted by this decision. Its a decision to take with the team.

If you work on a server api, you should choose one in agreement with your sysop team (or force them, depends your context).

You are working on packages to be distributed (cli), go for the LTS v4, it s going to be more stable.

You do not have constraints ? Go for v4 for stability, v6 for the latest features about es6 for example.

hth!!

Comment: Great,  Thanx for the feedback. I'll just try the 6. I can always uninstall (I hope :-D )